# Suggestion on tag name for an R package "ReporteRs"

Tags: discussion

[R: Insert table in template table using ReporteRs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26332856/r-insert-table-in-template-table-using-reporters)

The question above ask a legitimate question about the package `ReporteRs` that a tag for the package should use assigned, but the name can be confusing when it is turned to lower case.

Any suggestion for the tag?

Comment: How about specific tag like [tag:r-reporters]?